# Server timeout while sending email newsletters to a large subscriber list using "Sendy"

Tags: php, .htaccess, email, amazon-ec2, sendy

We are using Sendy to send email newsletters to our large email subscriber list of 450,000. We are using an Amazon t2.Medium instance with 4GB of Memory and our email sending rate is 6 per second.  We have already updated our php.ini and .htaccess settings to allow unlimited max_execution_time and have increased our memory_limit to 4000MB.  However, despite these precautions, our server still times out overnight.

```
[Wed Jul 26 05:06:27.190171 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 31182] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
```

Is this simply an issue of needing to increase our EC2 instance size? Or are we missing something?  Will creating a cron job help offset the timeout due to memory exhaustion?  Any help you can give us to better configure our server settings to prevent server timeouts while using Sendy would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Sendy on a t2.small instance without any problems. However when my lists started to surpass > 50k subscribers a cronjob for sending and importing csv lists were quite needed. It's quite easy to setup like this:

`sudo crontab -e`

Then make a cronjob that checks every 5 min for sendings:

`*/5 * * * * php /<sendy installation path>/scheduled.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Also if you have big lists I'd strongly recommend having a cronjob for that also:

`*/1 * * * * php /<sendy installation path>/import-csv.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Also worth noting that when running PHP in CLI mode the default configuration has no timeout limit.